# What does the parameter in Promise.tryComplete refer to?

Tags: scala, promise, future

Can anyone tell me what does the parameter refer to in the `tryComplete` function?

```
def any[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[T] = {
   val p = Promise[T]()

   fs foreach (x => x.onComplete(p.tryComplete(_)))

   p.future
}
```

I know the underscore here is of type `Try[T]`. Where does this `Try[T]` come from?

Comment: `x.onComplete(p.tryComplete(_))` ~ `x.onComplete(_ => p.tryComplete(_))`

Comment: The input parameter for onComplete should be "Try[T] => U". So how to understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning. Since `fs` is a `List[Future[T]]`, you know `x` is a `Future[T]`.

You need to register a callback that will fire when the result of `x` becomes available. The easy way to do this is with `onComplete`, which takes a function of type `Try[T] => U`.

So the underscore is a `Try[T]`, which holds the result of `x`, the `Future[T]`. There are two possible results for a `Future`: `Success[T]`, when the `Future[T]` worked and holds a result, and `Failure[T]`, which holds an exception because the `Future[T]` didn't work.

So `Try` is similar to `Option`, a way to safely represent an outcome.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Try[T] holds the result of x. Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Simply put, yes. But it is still important to know how to use that result within the context of a `Try` monad. Also, if the answer helped, an upvote and/or accept would be nice.

Comment: I would like to upvote but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry.

Comment: Haha true. No worries. Well, Scala is a tough but powerful language I am still learning as well. Good luck with your efforts!

Comment: "Since fs is a List[Future[Future[T]]" should be List[Future[T]], shouldn't?

Comment: Another question that what happens if I use "Promise.complete" instead of "Promise.tryComplete" ?

Answer (score 0):

`onComplete` accepts a function. The underscore receives the first parameter to that function. In case there are multiple underscores, the first underscore refers to the first parameter, the second underscore to the second parameter and so on.

Comment: I know the underscore here is of type Try[T]. I am wondering where does this Try[T] come from?